# React native & StyleSheets - Element is not so smooth with transform selector

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

How to make it more smooth. I can see that the line border is visible pixeled.

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerShape: {
    height: 30,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    backgroundColor: '#114FD4',
    transform: [{skewY: '-2deg'}],
    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
    zIndex: -1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 45,
  },
})
```